# Get sales order detail Dynamics web Microsoft 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I need to call the api from Java web to Dynamics 365 online web of Microsoft. I can acquire the access token. But I don't know how to call api to fetch a sales order detail.

I read the document from Microsoft but have no idea how to do.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/salesorderdetail?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9

Comment: any follow up questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool for generating API URL in dynamics CRM:
https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder
first of all, you should import the solution in dynamics 365 after that you can open the app with a button on the solutions view

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the repository, but when I open the Xrm.RESTBuilder.htm file, its crash the UI, and I cannot click any button like the demo picture show.

Comment: @Long, just download the Managed solution zip file from https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder/releases and import it in CRM. You can get ajax working snippet too once imported the builder. I shared more details in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The web api endpoint to get particular `salesorderdetail` will look like: (with respective GUID)

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/salesorderdetails(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)
```

To get all the `salesorderdetail` records:

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/salesorderdetails
```

To get all the `salesorderdetail` records for particular `salesorder`:

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/salesorderdetails?$filter=_salesorderid_value eq 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

The complete code snippet will be like: (using `XMLHttpRequest` in JS)

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/salesorderdetails?$filter=_salesorderid_value eq 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                var salesorderdetailid = results.value[i]["salesorderdetailid"];
            }
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just check and see that currently I used ERP, not CRM, so I cannot call api like /api/data. Its always throw 404 when I tried to.

Comment: @Long, oh okay. this link may be helpful - https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-forum/395890/creating-json-rest-api-in-d365-f-o